# Python: Overflow encountered in double-scalars

Tags: python, nan, odeint

I have a system of 5 differential equations that I am solving using odeint and I am running into divide by zero error in one of my differential equations. To by pass it, I tried two methods-
(a) one creating a function and returning 0.1 if denominator ever hit 0
(b) adding a small positive number to the denominator. 
However both are not giving me desired results. 
When I am not using either of these two solution, my code is running properly and I am getting desired graphs till the denominator goes 0. I have also attached the graphs. As we can see, the graphs are getting drawn correctly till just after 3 seconds after which the value becomes "nan" due to divide by zerror. Kindly help me get rid of this problem! Thanks in advance
PFA[image]

My code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t=np.linspace(0,250,10000)
c=5
k=50
eta=2.5
gamma,gamma1,gamma2=10,9,10
b,a1,a2=2,3,4
def check(x1,u,a1,x2,a2,b):
    return (.1 if np.sin(x1)==0 else b*(1/(np.sin(x1)))*u-a1*x2-a2*x1**2)


def f(Y,t):
    x1,x2,h,h1,h2=Y[0],Y[1],Y[2],Y[3],Y[4]
    #x"+a1x'+a2x^2=bcosec(x)u
    e=x1-np.sin(t)
    de=x2-np.cos(t)
    s=c*e+de
    u=-k*s-eta*np.tanh(s)+s*h1*x2+np.sin(x1)*h2*x1**2-np.sin(x1)*h*np.sin(t)-h*np.sin(t)*c*de-h*np.cos(x1)*s/2
    x1dot=x2
    #x2dot=b*(1.0/(np.sin(x1)+1e-8))*u-a1*x2-a2*x1**2
    x2dot=check(x1,u,a1,x2,a2,b)
    hdot=gamma*(s*np.tanh(10*np.sin(x1))*(s*np.cos(x1)/2+np.sin(x1)*np.sin(t)-np.sin(x1)*c*de))
    h1dot=gamma1*(s*np.tanh(10*np.sin(x1))*np.sin(x1)*x2)
    h2dot=gamma2*(s*np.tanh(10*np.sin(x1))*np.sin(x1)*x1**2)
    return[x1dot,x2dot,hdot,h1dot,h2dot]

y0=[0.1,0.2,0,0,0]
sol=odeint(f,y0,t,mxstep=500000,atol=1e-6)
x=sol[:,0]
xd=sol[:,1]
h=sol[:,2]
h1=sol[:,3]
h2=sol[:,4]
e,de=x-np.sin(t),xd-np.cos(t)
s=c*e+de
u=-k*s-eta*np.tanh(s)+s*h1*xd+np.sin(x)*h2*x**2-np.sin(x)*h*np.sin(t)-h*np.sin(t)*c*de-h*np.cos(x)*s/2
plt.subplot(2,3,1)
plt.plot(t,x,t,e,'r--')
plt.subplot(2,3,2)
plt.plot(x,xd)
plt.subplot(2,3,3)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.subplot(2,3,4)
plt.plot(t,h)
plt.subplot(2,3,5)
plt.plot(t,h1)
plt.subplot(2,3,6)
plt.plot(t,h2)
print(x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

in `check` you have

```
    if np.sin(x1)==0
```

which compares a numpy floating point family value to an integer for an exact match.  While mathematically you only get an undefined value for the inverse of 0, in computer floating point taking the inverse of a very small number can drive you into something that is larger than can be represented.  Try checking if your sine is less than `math.exp(math.log(2.0) * -32.0)`. This value is something small that can be represented exactly as a float in binary, which would not be true of a decimal like 0.000000001 converted to a binary floating point number.

Comment: No it is still not working, I am getting the output as zero after certain time instance. I mean I tried changing the check function with logic as you suggested but it still is not giving me correct answer.

Comment: I modified my check function as follows-
{def check(x1,u,a1,x2,a2,b):
    p=1.0/np.sin(x1)
    if np.sin(x1)<=1e-6 and np.sin(x1)>=0:
        l=1e-6
        return b*(1.0/l)*u-a1*x2-a2*x1**2
    elif np.sin(x1)>=-1e-6 and np.sin(x1)<0:
        l=-1e-6
        return b*(1.0/l)*u-a1*x2-a2*x1**2
    else:
        return b*(1.0/np.sin(x1))*u-a1*x2-a2*x1**2}